# Thue equation in function fields over finite field.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Is there any material on Thue equation in  function field over a finite field.

All I could find is a excellent research item on Thue equation over function field

Comment: Well, no function field is finite; do you mean function fields over a finite field?

Comment: @Lubin, yes, Sir,  function field over a finite field.

Comment: Ordinarily, when one speaks of number-theoretic matters and refers to “function fields”, one means for the base to be a finite field.